# Store JSON data in one field in DB and use it in flutter app

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have some data that i want to store in DB, this is what i store in my database in a field called "details":

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1"
  }
]
```

So when i get that table data and i encode it to be as an API it looks like this :

```
   .
   .
   .
"id": 1,
"details": " [\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": 1,\r\n    \"name\": \"name1\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n\t\"id\": 1,\r\n    \"name\": \"name1\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n\t\"id\": 1,\r\n    \"name\": \"name1\"\r\n  }\r\n]\r\n",
   .
   .
   .
```

I don't know how to get that "details" data and use it in my flutter app. this is the model i tried so far but it didn't work :

```
import 'dart:convert';

class MyModel {
    int _id;
    DetailModel _details;

  MyModel(game) {
      _id = game['id'];
      _details = DetailModel.fromJson(json.encode(game['details']));
  }

  int get id => _id;
    DetailModel get details => _details;
}

class DetailModel {
  List<DetailM> _details = [];

  DetailModel.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    List<DetailM> temp = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < parsedJson['details'].length; i++) {
      DetailM detail = DetailM(parsedJson['details'][i]);
      temp.add(detail);
    }
    _details = temp;
  }

  List<DetailM> get details => _details;
}

class DetailM {
    int _id;
    String _name;

  DetailM(detail) {
      _id = detail['id'];
      _name = detail['name'];
  }

    int get id => _id;
    String get name => _name;
}
```

The error i'm getting here is :

```
Error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

**json.encode()** returns a String...

Try

```
_details = DetailModel.fromJson(json.decode(game['details']));
```

Passes it as a map

Comment: `DetailModel.fromJson` expect `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` as a parameter but as you can see `game['details']` is a String

Comment: There is not part showing game['details'] is a string but if it is I'll update the response